# How to force the execution of a script when / is not mounted?

Tags: boot, embedded

I have bricked a linux embedded device.

I was experimenting with it, and added my own path to `/etc/ld.so.conf`. The `libc` I included in my path is not compatible with this particular device, so I lost ssh access to it and of course it does not boot anymore.

I can enter a sort of download mode, where I can load in memory the bootloader, the kernel, the dtb and the initramfs. I can then tell the processor to jump to a certain address in memory, and have the system boot.

This does not solve the problem, because as soon as the `root` is switched from the initramfs to the flash memory of the device, the wrong libraries are used and the device stops working.

My plan is to add a custom script to the initramfs that mounts the flash, erases `/etc/ld.so.conf` and `/etc/ld.so.cache`. I don't care if the deivice does not boot then, as soon as the files are emptied and the device is reboot, it should fall back to use the standard libraries. I can then connect via ssh and clean up the mess.

I was not able to understand where exactly I should inject my fix in the initramfs, so the question is:

**Where should I insert a few lines of bash so that they are executed at boot, before `/` is mounted?**

Comment: If anybody needs further details or insights, please do ask in the comments and I will more than happily edit the question.

Comment: You could tell `linux` to only use `initramfs` as the root filesystem. Next you can mount flash and copy files around. Can you pass custom parameters to the kernel?

Comment: Hi @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, I do not know how to tell `linux` to use only initramfs. I am not able to pass parameters to the kernel because of my lack of understanding of the U-Boot structure.

Comment: Can you do `printenv bootargs` in `uboot`?

Comment: You could also recompile your `linux` with a modified `init` script that this operation once. Anyway, if you want to modify `initramfs` you need to recompile whole `linux`, that's how it works.

Comment: I am not sure of what you mean @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, I have the `uboot` tree on my dev machine and I load the `.imx` file via usb using `imx_usb_loader`. I would gladly modify `init` and recompile the kernel, but I do not know `linux` that well and I don't fully understand the boot process. I suggest you expand your `init` solution into an answer...

Comment: I am not sure of what you mean @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, I have the `uboot` tree on my dev machine and I load the `.imx` file via usb using `imx_usb_loader`. I would gladly modify `init` and recompile the kernel, but I do not know `linux` that well and I don't fully understand the boot process. I suggest you expand your `init` solution into an answer...

Comment: I don't know the details of your setup - you have to modify `linux` parameters to use `initramfs` that has a working shell and at least `mount` and working network stack to mount external utilities such as `ubiattach` or whatever you will need. You can hardcode them in `.config` and I think this is what should be done here.

Comment: If you already have a working `linux` that contains `initramfs` you may only need to modify its `init` part - it may be `/init`. You will need to recompile it anyway. Or you can unsolder the flash, replace it or erase it in an external programmer, or you can use some vendor specific tools to erase the flash contents and write something new to it.

Answer (score 1):

Add your shell script code into the file `/init` in your `initramfs` image.

Don't use anything too fancy - `/bin/sh` won't be `bash`, it will likely be `busybox`.

Read the sections starting with `What is initramfs?` in [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt) doc.